# How to safely use the post method to submit code in a form in Node / Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm pretty new to Node and Express and wanted to be able to submit javascript safely through an input. How can one safely execute a user's submitted code on a page?

**user input:**

```
<script>alert('hi');</script> or some html...
```

**html:**

```
<input name="myInputField" />
```

**node/express:**

```
Using router.post('/code', function(req,res,next) {
  let js = req.body.myInputField;
  res.render('./myPage', {code:js});
...
```

Comment: There are no risks to your server during the form post.   Any risks that would come up depend entirely upon what you do with the user input on your server.  That's where vulnerabilities come from.  If you're going to inject it directly into a web page, you may want to make sure that it can only display as text and cannot be executed.  You can do that by escaping all HTML special characters in it (so it can only displayed as plain text) or by using JS to directly insert the string into a DOM node as a text node (again so it can only be displayed as text).

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 - I do actually want to execute it on a web page. I'm working on something similar to jsfiddle. Any tips on how to do that safely?

Comment: That's a long topic usually involving separate domains (to prevent access to ajax and cookies), iframes, sandbox features, etc...  Just look at what jsFiddle does.